# How to send `<menu>` key to iTerm?

Tags: iterm, emacs

I know that there is a setting, iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > Keys > Key Mappings.

But where can I find hexcode for Menu/App key that is present in Windows keyboards, so that I can use it as a keybinding in a text editor like Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

This [Windows site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) lists two options for the menu key with hex codes for virtual keyboards:

a left menu key `0xA4`

a right menu key `0xA5`

This kind of information is useful for MacOS as well, so here is [a site with virtual key hex codes for MacOS](http://www.meandmark.com/keycodes.html).

And finally, in 2010 someone else asked for [a list of Mac virtual key codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202629/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-mac-virtual-key-codes/16125341)  on StackOverflow, which is a fantastic and informative read to include here.

Comment: I have tried `Send Hex Codes` option, but is there option to actually select `Send`? because with `Send Hex Codes: 0xA5` it outputs literal character `\244`. Here is screenshot of my setting https://imgur.com/a/DRNnmiM

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your problem. I assumed you were using iTerm on a Mac to remotely access a Windows computer and needed/wanted to trigger the menu key. If this is not the case, please give a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Almost correct, I am using iTerm on Mac but accessing Ubuntu Linux box

Comment: What does the menu key on a windows keyboard normally trigger in Ubuntu?